# Ajax Request Not Returning Data Added During Initial AJAX Reqest in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having a problem in Internet Explorer only, where my Basket Count isn't updating when I Add To Basket.

**The Code**

Below is the code that runs when the Add To Basket button is clicked....

```
        if($(this).attr('class')==='addToCart'){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../includes/add-product.php?accountID=' + localStorage.getItem("username"),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('data ' + data);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    basketCount();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }); 
    }
```

I've excluded what I consider to be irrelevant code, along with most of the parameters passed through to add-product.php
This seems to work well in all browsers... The data is added to the database and as a bit of a test, at the end of add-product.php, I echo back "Data Added".

The problem is with the basketCount function which works well in other browsers, just not IE.

```
function basketCount() {    
    "use strict";
    console.log('basketCount running');
    var basketCount = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: '../includes/basket-count.php',
        data: 'accountID=' + accountID,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {       
            console.log('sql result ' + data);
            $(data).each(function(key, value) {
                basketCount += parseInt(value.qty);
                console.log('basketCount loop ' + basketCount);
            });
            $('#cartCount').html(basketCount);
            console.log('basketCount ' + basketCount);
        }
    });
}
```

**The problem**

basket-count.php isn't seeing the data that was added via add-product.php

**The Results**

The console always returns "Data Added", which I'm echoing from add-product.php

For the first product I try to add, the console shows...

```
sql result null
basketCount 0
```

For a second product, the console shows...

```
sql result [object Object]
basketCount loop 1
basketCount 1
```

It always appears to be one entry behind and can't take into account what's just been added.

**Attempted Solutions**

1) Call basketCount in complete: instead of success:

2) Add setTimeout delay, which was set at 5 seconds until I could see "Data Added" was getting logged before "basketCount running", so I've assumed timing isn't the problem.

3) Merging basketCount functionality with add-product.php, which I want to avoid, as basketCount is used in other areas such as remove-product.php and update-basket.php etc

**Thoughts**

According to the console, the basketCount function appears to be running after the data has been added and the function itself works correctly, even in IE, so I'm confused as to why it's not seeing the data that has just been inserted.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so solution 3 obviously wasn't attempted well yesterday, because this morning it works well in IE and although some Basket Count code is repeated against the add, remove, update, cancel etc functionality, from what I've read, it's probably more efficient that making mulitple ajax requests.